# Can't extract pattern from filename

Tags: unix, sed

Getting errors from the following sed command:

```
echo 20130521_OnePKI_p107336_APP.pfx | sed -e 's/_\([pP][0-9]+\)_/\1/'
```

Instead of returning `p107336`, it is returning the full filenam `20130521_OnePKI_p107336_APP.pfx`.

Any ideas why this is happening, and how I can restrict the output to only the pattern I would like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The captures should be escaped parentheses and you can use case-insensitive match `i`, also, you are replacing the capture part with the captured part so no changes are made. This one matches the entire line and replaces it with the captured pattern:

```
sed -e 's/.*_\([pP][0-9][0-9]*\)_.*/\1/'
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working on SunOS:
>echo 20130521_OnePKI_p107336_APP.pfx | sed -e 's/.*_\(p[0-9][0-9]*\)_.*/\1/i'
sed: command garbled: s/.*_\(p[0-9][0-9]*\)_.*/\1/i

Answer (score 1):

An easier way might be to use grep:

```
echo 20130521_OnePKI_p107336_APP.pfx | egrep -o "[pP][0-9]+"
```

The "-o" tells grep to only print the matching part of the input.

Comment: Unfortunately on my version of SunOS, egrep doesn't have the `-e` option for me to use

Comment: Bummer! Oh well, "man egrep" or "man grep" might turn up something similar.

Answer (score 1):

The regex `[pP][0-9]+` in principle matches any substring that begins with either `p` or `P` followed by one or more digits. The string `"20130521_OnePKI_p107336_APP.pfx"` has a substring matching that pattern so the whole string matches the regex.

When grouping with parenthesis around the whole regex on the left side and referring to it on the right side like you did in `'s/([pP][0-9]+)/\1/'` you're basically saying "replace the match with itself", which will naturally result in the same string as had in the first place.

What you need here is to match the *whole* string from beginning and then group a part of that string, as already indicated. Then you can refer to that part on the right side to extract it from the bigger string.

You will need to appropriately escape the expression when working in a shell.

Comment: @htor regarding your explanation, should a command like this not work?  
echo 20130521_OnePKI_p107336_APP.pfx | sed -e 's/^.*\([pP][0-9]\+\).*$/\1/'  
As I am still receiving the whole filename  
echo 20130521_OnePKI_p107336_APP.pfx | sed -e 's/^.*\([pP][0-9]\+\).*$/\1/' 20130521_OnePKI_p107336_APP.pfx

Answer (score 0):

You must escape parens and `+`. Also match all the string and substitute all it only with the part you wish (`.*` before and end your string):

```
... | sed -e 's/^.*\([pP][0-9]\+\).*$/\1/'
```

Comment: Hi, This doesn't seemt to work unfortunately:
>echo 20130521_OnePKI_p107336_APP.pfx | sed -e 's/^.*\([pP][0-9]\+\).*$/\1/'
20130521_OnePKI_p107336_APP.pfx

Comment: @user185572: Sorry. It worked for me. Did you escape parens too?